# Problem after system update. Root permission denied, user lib permission denied

Tags: permissions, root, opensuse

As I updated opensuse 11.1 with update packages from october and november 2009, I couldnt use the command ping. For `root` it gives `Permission denied` and for a `regular user` I get

```
libresolv.so.2: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied.
```

The other coulprit besides the update could be the instalation of google-chrome (.deb file to .rpm, some symbolic links for libs to make chrome work).

When the system rebooted, X server also became blank. Before the reboot it worked, as did chrome, but the ping command didnt work even before the reboot.

Any ideas? I ran some sort of disk check from a rescue CD, libresolv seems as other libs, root has uid=0 ...

Comment: Please provide output of two commands: strace ping 127.0.0.1;  ls -al /usr/lib/libresolv*   (or wherever it is)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for feedback, but I have fixed the issue with glibc packet update. Seems the lib got corrupted or something.

Comment: libresolv is part of glibc, and had probably bad permission settings. The glibc upgrade overwrote the libresolv and fixed its permissions as well.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked wether selinux is active or not?
perhaps there went something wrong. try to start with selinux=0 on your grub/lilo commandline.